# Grepping or filtering Xcode "Devices" console

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

I'm debugging a Corona SDK app that I'm running on my iPhone. As I run the app it sends debug info that I can see in the Xcode "Devices" panel. Unfortunately that same console is littered with OS logs which make my own app's logs offscreen very fast. I can copy those into a file and grep them after I'm done but I would like to do so realtime so that I *only* see my own app's logs.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc

```
Open /Applications/Utilities/Console.app
```

MacOS 10.12 and above. Works with AppleWatch.

Comment: Please tell me this works with iOS! This would be just great.

Answer (score 6):

Just found this tool:

> https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/

I have nothing to do with that company, just thought I post it here, because I wish I had found it earlier!

Just install and you can live filter the device console - awesome :)!

Comment: Haven't tried it but it looks really good! You'd figure this feature would be implemented in Xcode. I can't see this taking more than 10 lines of code...

Comment: @Julian IIRC I had to go out of my way and get a plugin just to add a filter to the xcode console. I wonder if such a plugin might also exist for the device console?

Comment: It's nice but my device keeps getting disconnected. It seems that they should fix a few of this connection issues :(

Answer (score 4):

After a few months of searching I found this:

https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx

It's a set of terminal commands that let you tail the device's logs and grep them to your heart's content.

EDIT: A couple of years after posting this question it seems Apple did include this feature not in Xcode but in the Console app. I've changed the accepted answer to Warren Stringer's to keep this question current.